# simply trying to show value when it's entered in input field (angular js)

Tags: angularjs, laravel

i am very new to laravel and angular js. The thing i want to do is to display display the span which inner value will be `placeholder` and there will be input field when user will enter any value then instead of that place holder new value of text field will be written there.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0-rc2" data-semver="1.2.0-rc2"   src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script>
   function Controller($scope) {
     $scope.data = {
       company_name : ''
      };

     $scope.isEmptyCompany = function () {
        return company_name === ''; 
      }
  }
</script>
</head>
  <body>
   <div ng-app ng-controller="Controller">
      <input type="text" ng-model="data.company_name"/>
      <div class="company_name">
          <h1 class="left">
              <span ng-if="data.company_name === ''">
                  Placeholder
              </span>
              <span ng-if="data.company_name!==''">
                  {{data.company_name}}
              </span>
          </h1>
      </div>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

it is displaying this error i don't know why it's happening

`Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\views\user\user_admin_info.blade.php)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel is processing your `{{ tag }}` instead of Angular. You need to tell Laravel to ignore your Angular tags:

```
@{{data.company_name}}
```

For more information, see "Blade & JavaScript Frameworks" under [Displaying Data](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data).

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to precede the curly braces with `@` symbol like described by @Ben. But when working with angular (IMHO) I think it's better to simply use `.php` views instead of `.blade.php` views because otherwise you would have to include @ everywhere in your views. And secondly in angular specific views, well there isn't always a whole lot of server side templating going on. Even if we need something we can use php's native `<?php ?>` templating.

Comment: Great point, agreed. Though for novice developers, blade is safer than raw PHP if they end up needing it.